# How do I fix an html rendering issue in Google Inbox (not present in Gmail) that adds abbreviation points

Tags: html, css, html-email, google-apps

I have created this email layout below, and cannot for the life of me figure out why Gmail renders it correctly, but Inbox renders it horribly.

[image: Rendering issue seen here. "..." everywhere!]

Upon inspection, it is for some reason separating a bunch of stuff into their own table elements. Anyone see something I'm missing. I'm very new to html for email, and am constantly shocked at how bad it can be.

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; font-family: verdana;">
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="center"><span style="color: rgb(44, 160, 209); font-size: 24px; font-family: verdana;">shift</span><span style="color: rgb(235, 42, 83); font-size: 24px; font-family: verdana; font-weight: bold;">Swap</span></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- This is where your content goes bro -->
  <tr>
    <td>
        <table width="600" bgcolor="#FFF" align="center" style="border-radius:8px;">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding: 35px;">
              <h3>
                Welcome <span style="text-decoration: none;"><%= @email %></span>!
              </h3>
              <div>
                <span style="display: block;">You can confirm your account email through the link below:</span>
                <br>
                <a href="<%= confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %>" target ="_blank" style="display: block; color: orange; text-decoration: none; font-size: 150%;">Confirm your account</a>
                <br>
                <span style="display: block;">Or paste the following into the address bar: <%= confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></span>
                <h3 style="padding-top: 20px;">Thanks for signing up. We're looking forward to seeing you on the site!</h3>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="50">
                <tr align="center"><td style="color: #2b2b2b";>Made by <a style="color: orange; text-decoration: none;" href="http://rafipatel.com">Rafi Patel</a> ©<%= Time.new.year %></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Here is what it looks like when Inbox for some reason hides the entire message, which seems to happen when I send a "reconfirm" message:

[image: Google Inbox when hidden by default?]

And Gmail:

[image: Gmail render]

Comment: Could you show how it looks in GMail? ... Also, why style a `span` as `display: block`? ... use a `div` ... and I recommend using table elements only, so instead of a `h3`, give the cell similar font settings instead

Comment: I updated. Honestly there was no reason for using a div, or a span. I just wasn't sure if email clients interpreted divs like I'm used to.

Comment: If you take out all non table elements, how does that look? ... I really recommend doing that, since even if it is 2016, mail clients are way behind

Comment: @LGSon Thanks, removing all h3 elements and spans etc has got it working. I've put them all int heir own table rows. It works like a charm! A really annoying charm.

Comment: You want me to post that as an answer?

Comment: @LGSon sure. It definitely fixed the issue, and I now know what not to do going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend to take out all non table elements, since even if it is 2016, mail clients are way behind

```html
<body style="margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; font-family: verdana;">
  <table width="100%" bgcolor="#F7F7F7" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="50%" align="right" style="color: rgb(44, 160, 209); font-size: 24px; font-family: verdana;padding-right: 0">
              shift              
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="left" style="color: rgb(235, 42, 83); font-size: 24px; font-family: verdana; font-weight: bold;padding-left: 0">
              Swap
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- This is where your content goes bro -->
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 35px;background: #FFF">
        <table width="600" bgcolor="#FFF" align="center" style="border-radius:8px;">
          <tr>
            <td style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 22px">
              Welcome
              @ email !
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 22px">
              You can confirm your account email through the link below:
            </td>            
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="<%= confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %>" target="_blank" style="display: block; color: orange; text-decoration: none; font-size: 150%;">Confirm your account</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Or paste the following into the address bar:
              confirmation_url
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding: 20px 0; font-size: 22px">
              Thanks for signing up. We're looking forward to seeing you on the site!
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="50">
          <tr align="center">
            <td style="color: #2b2b2b">Made by <a style="color: orange; text-decoration: none;" href="http://rafipatel.com">Rafi Patel</a> ©
              <%=T ime.new.year %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing how "fussy" e-mail clients are, there's one thing that I see that may be causing unpredictable results.  It's a long-shot that this will fix anything other than a typing error; but within that line of code, do you see what I see near 'color: 2b2b2b'?

```
<td style="color: #2b2b2b";>Made by <a style="color: orange; text-decoration: none;" href="http://rafipatel.com">Rafi Patel</a> ©<%= Time.new.year %></td>
```

The semi-colon is outside of the style attribute.  Prolley just a foul ball, but you never know.  ;)